# Add video in xhtml that is view able on all platforms

Tags: video, xhtml

how would i add a video into xhtml, that pulls the content of the video from the server and not like youtube,

would this be valid ? or would i be best using the normal html method ?

```
<!-- First, try the applet -->
<object
    src="http://www.example.com/applets/classes/TheEarth.class"
    srctype="application/x-java-applet">
      <!-- Else, try the video -->
      <object
          src="TheEarth.mpeg"
          srctype="video/mpeg"
          xml:base="http://www.example.com/videos/">
            <!-- Else, try the image -->
            <object
                src="TheEarth.png"
                srctype="image/png"
                xml:base="http://www.example.com/images/">
                <!-- Else process the alternate text -->
                The <strong>Earth</strong> as seen from space.
            </object>
      </object>
</object>
```

also what is the best solution to make it work on all platforms, like andriod, ios, windows, chrome etc

Comment: attribute srctype does not exist, try using type instead.